# How to include a column from another table in the query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a table named `Payments` and another table named `Students` with the field `name`.

In my Controller Payment, I want to retrieve the student names.

I have this:

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $user = $request->user();
    $payments = Payment::query()
        ->when($user->hasRole('admin') !== true, function (Builder $query) use ($user) {
            $query->where('email', $user->email);
        })
        ->when($request->has('search'), function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%');
        })
        ->paginate(5);

    return view('admin.payments.index', compact('payments'))
        ->with('display_search', $user->hasRole('admin'));
}
```

How do I join the students table?

```
payment::whereHas('students'
```

I don't know where I have to put this line

**Edit:**

When I add a payment, I always have the same student which appears ???

[image]

I think the problem is here ?? In my request ???

```
$query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%');
         })->with('students:id,name') // Here
        ->paginate(5);
```

Index blade

```
<th>Date payment</th>
<th>Number seance</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Total</th>
 <th>Name</th>

</tr>
</thead>
@foreach($payments as $payment)
<tr>
   <td> {{$payment->date_payment->format('d/m/Y') }}</td>
   <td> {{$payment->number_seance}}</td>
   <td> {{$payment->price}}</td>
   <td> {{$payment->total}}</td>
   <td> {{$payment->students->first()->name}}</td> 
   <td>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `Payment::with('students');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eager load the name column from the relationship

```php
$payments = Payment::query()
    ->when($user->hasRole('admin') !== true, function (Builder $query) use ($user) {
        $query->where('email', $user->email);
    })
    ->when($request->has('search'), function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%');
    })->with('students:id,name') // Here
    ->paginate(5);
```

Provided you have the relationship setup in the `Payment` model

```php
public function students()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Student');
}
```

And a `payment_id` column in the `students` table referencing the `id` in the `payments` table as a foreign key

```php
Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('payment_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('payment_id')->references('id')->on('payments');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Access a single student in the collection

```html
<td>{{ $payment->students->first()->name }}</td>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you a lot (sahit) for your help. I have a problem `Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View:` my problem is here I think ?  `$query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%');
    })->with('students:id,name')`

Comment: You're welcome (Bla mziya), edit your question and post the blade view

Comment: I updated my answer, aren't you getting the student name inside a foreach? Each Payment have many students no?

Comment: Yes, I have a foreach, my last problem is that when I add a payment, I always have the same student which appears ??? I have edited my first message.